# How can I count the number of partitions of S with exactly n parts?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

If I have a set $S$ of $n$ elements, is there a way to find the number of partitions of that set with $k$ "parts/cells"?

For example, if set $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$, there are 15 total partitions of that set, and 6 of them have 3 parts/cells:

$$
[\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c, d\}]\\
[\{a\}, \{c\}, \{b, d\}]\\ 
[\{a\}, \{d\}, \{b, c\}]\\  
[\{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, d\}]\\ 
[\{b\}, \{d\}, \{a, c\}]\\ 
[\{c\}, \{d\}, \{a, b\}]
$$

Comment: The number of ways is called a Stirling Number of the Second Kind. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 2):

This is the number of orbits of surjective functions $[k]\leftarrow[n]$ under (composition on the left with) permutations of the elements of $[k]$ (since the parts are not explicitly labeled). Here $[i]$ denotes your favorite $i$-element set, for $i\in\Bbb N$. As such [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_sx) is contained in the [Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).